# how does closure help a function to knowing the previous function call's private variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand closure, I thought I understood it until I came across the following solution:

I don't understand how this will alert 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
var next = (function(){
    var r = 0;
  return function(){
    return r++;
  }

})()

for (var i = 0; i<=5; i++){
    alert(next());
}
```

I understand how the first iteration works, just having `next`, the function will execute and return the return function, then the extra `()` after next will execute that returned function.
I also understand that the return function when executed will have access to the variable r because of Closure.

However I don't understand how on the next iteration, the state of r will persist.
On the next iteration when `next()` get run again, the `r` variable will be inside the function scope and won't get affected by anything in the global, how is it that it knows the state of the r in the previous `next()`. Even if it does, wouldn't `var r = 0` reset `r` back to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer IIFE runs only *once*, as indicated by the `()` at the end:

```
var next = (function(){
  var r = 0;
  return function(){
    return r++;
  }
})()
  ^^
```

So, when the interpreter comes across the `var next = ...` line, the IIFE runs, creates the `r` variable, and then returns the following function:

```
function(){
  return r++;
}
```

`next` is assigned to the result of calling the IIFE, and the IIFE returns that function. So, in the future, when you call `next`, you're calling that (small) function above - calling `next` doesn't call the whole IIFE again, and there's only ever one binding for the `r` variable.

Were `next` an *uninvoked* function that created an `r`, you'd be right, every invocation of `next` would create a new function with a new binding for `r`:

```js
var next = function(){
  var r = 0;
  return function(){
    return r++;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i<=5; i++){
  var theFn = next();
  console.log(theFn());
}
```